# Using image_url helper in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helpermethods

I'm trying to use the image_url helper in my model. I also have an image_url property on the model(can't be changed). When I call image_url, the helper method it appears to be calling the method on the model. I get the error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

```
 def public_image
    if self.avatar && photo_public?
      self.avatar.remote_url
    else
      image_url '/client/src/assets/images/icons/anon-small.svg'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think you're running into a naming collision and I believe ruby will execute the first method matched which is image_url on your model and not the helper method, you should namespace your helper methods so you could do something  like: `Model::Helper.image_url(path)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`image_url` is a view helper, it should not be used inside the model, you should move that logic to a helper for the view

```
#application_helper.rb
def public_image(user)
  if user.avatar && user.photo_public?
    user.avatar.remote_url
  else
    image_url '/client/src/assets/images/icons/anon-small.svg'
  end
end
```

In your view change `user.public_image` to `public_image(user)`

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree with arieljuod that this is a view concern. However, in case it's really needed for a dirty implementation, it is possible to do `Object.new.extend(ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper).image_url('foo')`

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it's very right, you can't call on that scope!
This isn't a method for a model.
This is an ActionView helper method.
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_url

For what I'm seeing this isn't the right place to have this logic. Consider putting this in a `decorator` to abstract this non-business logic.